# JS not working (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working on a website with `WordPress` and i have adapted a code from `codepen` creating [my version of it](https://codepen.io/santandrea/pen/OzRymz) to implement it on the site.

```js
var slideshow = document.querySelector('[data-slideshow]')
    slides = slideshow.querySelectorAll('[data-slide]')
for (j=0;j<slides.length;j++){
  slides[j].setAttribute('data-slide',j)
}
var count = 0
function move(direction){
  if (direction == 'prev'){
    if (document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+(count-1)+'"]')){
      document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+(count-1)+'"]').style.left = '-100vw'
    }
    document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+count+'"]').style.left = '0'
    if (document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+(count+1)+'"]')){
      document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+(count+1)+'"]').style.left = '100vw'
    }
    if (count-1 >= 0){
      count--
    }
  }
  if (direction == 'next'){
    document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+count+'"]').style.left = '-100vw'
    if (document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+(count+1)+'"]')){
      document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+(count+1)+'"]').style.left = '0'
    }
    if (document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+(count+2)+'"]')){
      document.querySelector('[data-slideshow] [data-slide="'+(count+2)+'"]').style.left = '100vw'
      count++
    }
  }
}
// Arrow keys to navigate
document.onkeyup = function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var charCode = e.which;
  charCode==37 && move('prev')
  charCode==39 && move('next')
}
// Swipe to Navigate
var gesture = {
      x: [],
      y: [],
      match: ''
    },
    tolerance = 100;
window.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  for (var i=0; i<e.touches.length; i++){
    var dot = document.createElement('div');
    dot.id = i
    dot.style.top = e.touches[i].clientY-25+'px'
    dot.style.left = e.touches[i].clientX-25+'px'
    document.body.appendChild(dot)
    gesture.x.push(e.touches[i].clientX)
    gesture.y.push(e.touches[i].clientY)
  }
});
window.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
  for (var i=0; i<e.touches.length; i++) {
    var dot = document.getElementById(i);
    dot.style.top = e.touches[i].clientY-25+'px'
    dot.style.left = e.touches[i].clientX-25+'px'
    gesture.x.push(e.touches[i].clientX)
    gesture.y.push(e.touches[i].clientY)
  }
});
window.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
  var dots = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
      xTravel = gesture.x[gesture.x.length-1] - gesture.x[0],
      yTravel = gesture.y[gesture.y.length-1] - gesture.y[0];
  if (yTravel<tolerance && yTravel>-tolerance && xTravel<-tolerance){
    move('next')
  }
  if (yTravel<tolerance && yTravel>-tolerance && xTravel>tolerance){
    move('prev')
  }
  gesture.x = []
  gesture.y = []
  gesture.match = xTravel = yTravel = ''
  for (i=0;i<dots.length;i++){
    dots[i].id = ''
    dots[i].style.opacity = 1
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.body.removeChild(dots[i])
    },1000)
  }
})
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

#icebtools ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}

p {
    font-weight: 200;
}

b {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

#post {
  background: #0677A4;
}

#post ::selection {
  background-color: #79cbf1 !important;
  text-shadow: #066D8C 2px 2px 2px ;
}

#interp {
  background: #974198;
}


 #interp ::selection {
 background-color: #d6b7da !important;
  text-shadow: #5d068c 2px 2px 2px;
}


#sources {
  background: #7FBA48;
}

#sources ::selection {
 background-color: #d1f5b5 !important;
    text-shadow: #226b18 2px 2px 2px;
}

#fakenews {
  background: #F16060;
}

#fakenews ::selection {
  background-color: #f7cbca !important;
    text-shadow: #d40000 2px 2px 2px;
}

#journal {
  background: #D77A27;
}

#journal ::selection {
  background-color: #FEC20F !important;
    text-shadow: #846000 2px 2px 2px;
}

#images {
  background: #D23182;
}

#images ::selection {
    background-color: #f3bbd8 !important;
    text-shadow: #840063 2px 2px 2px;
}

#numbers {
  background: #6DB7E5;
}

#numbers ::selection {
  background-color: #07a8e2 !important;
    text-shadow: #493cbf 2px 2px 2px;
}

.slide h1 {
    text-align: center;
  color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#content-slide {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.section p {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.section2 {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.section2 p {
  float: right;
  text-align: justify;
  direction:rtl;
  width: 70%;
}

.section3 {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.section3 p {
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  direction:ltr;
  width: 70%;
}

.section-line {
  
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  
}

.section-linetxt  {
    float: left;
  width: 70%;
    
}

#journalp p {
  width: 100%;
  direction: ltr;
}

#pbr {
     padding-bottom: 20%;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

#fb-link img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 45%;
  width: 40px;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}

#eximg img{
  width:80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#eximg2 img {
  width: 55%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#eximg3 img {
   width: 55%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

#btm-txt {
  height: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
}

[data-slideshow] {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
[data-slide] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100vmax;
  z-index: 50;
  transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
[data-slide]:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
}
[data-slideshow] nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1em;  
  top: 45%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#nav-left {
  left: .75em;
}

#nav-right {
  right: .75em;
}
[data-slideshow] nav input {
  font-size: 50pt !important;
  margin: 0 .25em !important;
  width: auto !important;
  min-width: 2.25em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
  color: white !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.7) 1px 1px 0 !important;
  transition: color .1s ease-in-out;
  border: none;
}

#btn-bck{
  float: left;
}

#btn-nxt {
  float: right
}

[data-slideshow] nav input:focus,
[data-slideshow] nav input:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
[data-slideshow] nav input:active {
  color: #0cf !important;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
[data-slide] h1 {
  margin: 10vmin 0 4vmin 0 !important;
  font-size: 12vmin !important;
}
[data-slide] h1 + h2 {
  margin-top: -4vmin !important;
}


@media (orientation: portrait) {
  [data-slideshow],
  [data-slide] {
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmax;
  }
}
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  [data-slideshow],
  [data-slide] {
    width: 100vmax;
    height: 100vmin;
  }
}
```

```html
<section data-slideshow id="icebtools">
  <article data-slide class="slide" id="post">
  <h1> Post </h1>
  
  <div id="content-slide">
    <div class="section" id="eximg">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7NguRlq.png">
    </div>
    
    <div class="section" id="fb-link">
      <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/33/33702.svg"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section">
      <p>Questo strumento ha l'obiettivo di far "ascoltare più <b>campane</b>". Sulla pagina facebook dedicata, condivideremo i post di politici e personaggi eminenti, suddivisi per argomento. Questi post andranno a riempire un <b>archivio pubblico</b> con due funzioni:
        <b>Informarsi velocemente</b> (ad esempio in vista delle elezioni) e verificare la <b>coerenza</b> dei politici a distanza di tempo. Sarà infatti possibile, grazie ad una ricerca interna, cliccare sul politico interessato, digitare l'argomento su cui ci si
        vuole informare e automaticamente si aprirà una schermata con tutti i post che quel politico ha scritto su quel determinato argomento.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  </article>
  
  <article data-slide id="interp" class="slide">
      <h1> Interpretation </h1>
  
  <div id="content-slide">
    <div class="section">
     <p>Ci troviamo nella maggior parte dei casi di fronte non al l'informazione ma all'interpretazione dell'informazione. I giornali interpretano, i politici interpretano. Per questo motivo Iceberg Interpretation metterà a disposizione degli utenti l'informazione oggettiva seguita da più pareri e interpretazioni. L'obiettivo è rendere consapevoli del fatto che ogni notizia è soggetta ad interpretazione ed è bene analizzarle tutte per avere un quadro trasparente della realtà</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section" id="eximg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sOGQSI0.png">
    </div>
    
    <div class="section" id="btm-txt">
      <p>               Investiamo così nella creazione del senso critico, spingendo alla riflessione per combattere l'innata spinta dell'uomo ad informarsi solo su fonti che confermano le proprie idee. Inoltre, in questa sezione, un'interessante ed innovativa interpretazione avverrà grazie allo studio del linguaggio del corpo. Degli esperti del settore analizzeranno i discorsi dei più eminenti politici e studieranno il linguaggio del corpo che costituisce il 70% del messaggio comunicativo, andremo sotto la punta dell'iceberg.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </article>
  
  <article data-slide class="slide" id="sources">
  <h1> Sources </h1>
  
         <div id="content-slide">
        <div class="section">
      <p> Questo strumento, che ha una sua propria pagina Facebook, condividerà solo informazioni provenienti da siti ufficiali. Le fonti saranno quindi il sito del governo e dei vari ministeri. Può sembrare scontato, ma in realtà ogni giorno i funzionari di governo hanno incontri, firmano atti, fanno proposte e molto altro, e una nostra attenta osservazione ai siti di informazione ci ha fatto notare come la maggior parte di queste notizie non vengano riportate. Riteniamo che per approvare o criticare l'operato del nostro governo sia necessario essere a conoscenza di quello che ogni giorno fa. 
      </p>
    </div>
 
    
    <div class="section" id="fb-link">
      <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/33/33702.svg"></a>
    </div>
    

    <div class="section" id="eximg">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/by34JOY.png">
    </div>
    

  </div>

  </article>
  
   
   
 <article data-slide class="slide" id="fakenews">
  <h1> Fake News </h1>
  
         <div id="content-slide">
        <div class="section2">
      <p> Questo strumento tratterà il delicato problema delle bufale. Vi saranno delle analisi sulle notizie false o parzialmente vere e analisi sulle fonti tendenzialmente poco attendibili.
Iceberg official site: questo strumento, che ha una sua propria pagina facebook, condividerà solo informazioni provenienti da siti ufficiali. Le fonti saranno quindi il sito del governo e dei vari ministeri. Può sembrare scontato, ma in realtà ogni giorno i funzionari di governo hanno incontri, firmano atti, fanno proposte e molto altro, e una nostra attenta osservazione ai siti di informazione ci ha fatto notare come la maggior parte di queste notizie non vengano riportate. Riteniamo che per approvare o criticare l'operato del nostro governo sia necessario essere a conoscenza di quello che ogni giorno fa
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="section2" id="eximg2">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/x3BGonq.png">
    </div>
    

  </div>
 </article>
  
  <article data-slide class="slide" id="journal">
  <h1> Journal </h1>
  
 
   <div id="content-slide">
    
    
        <div class="section2" id="journalp">
          
                 
    <div class="section-line">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/r7vE3OA.png">
    </div>
          
          <div class="section-linetxt">
      <p id="pbr"> Questo strumento ci terrà informati solo sul campo internazionale. Tradurremo articoli di grandi <b>testate straniere</b>, tra cui quelle orientali; l'obiettivo è spingere il lettore a riflettere su cosa "dicono a noi" e su cosa "dicono a loro", per riuscire a farsi un'idea più trasparente di quello che accade nel mondo.
      </p>
          
         <p>
           L'obiettivo ultimo sarà quello di realizzare un giornale indipendente con foto, articoli, video e tutti i contenuti con cui potremo stimolare la riflessione su quello che succede fuori dal nostro paese.
          </p>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section2" id="eximg3">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TV0CwxZ.png">
    </div>
    

  </div>
  </article>
  
  <article data-slide class="slide" id="images">
  <h1> Images </h1>
  
        <div id="content-slide">
        <div class="section2">
      <p>Questo strumento pubblicherà vignette, meme e brevi storie raccontate sotto forma di fumetto. Lo scopo sarà quello di spingere alla riflessione utilizzando la SATIRA e l'arte del disegno.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="section2" id="eximg2">
     <img src="https://s9.postimg.org/vvjyp10fj/iceberg_section-11.png">
    </div>
    
    

  </div>
 </article>
  
  <article data-slide class="slide" id="numbers">
  <h1>Numbers</h1>
  
  <div id="content-slide">  
    
    <div class="section2" id="eximg3">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/eJJfoAy.png">
    </div>
    
         
        <div class="section3">
      <p>Questo strumento tratterà i numeri. Verranno quindi riportati i dati come l'andamento del PIL, debito pubblico, spese, entrate ecc. e saranno inoltre pubblicati diversi SONDAGGI.
      </p>
    </div>

    

  </div>
 </article>
  
  <nav id="nav-left">
    <input id="btn-bck" type=button data-button=outline value=&lt; onclick=move('prev') ontouchstart=move('prev')>
     </nav>
    <nav id="nav-right">
    <input  id="btn-nxt" type=button data-button=outline value=&gt; onclick=move('next') ontouchstart=move('next')>
 </nav>
</section>
```

Everything is working fine on `codepen` and as you can see there's no link related to the `JavaScript`, and also I have imported the other in my header so every part of the code is the same [here](http://icebergcultura.com) (the site where it goes) and there on `codepen`.

but if you check in the console inside the website you can see that `querySelectorAll` cannot read [data-slide], I don't really know well `JavaScript` so I'm stuck here not knowing what to do.

On my `WordPress` cms there are only 4 plugins that are mostly for syntax highlights and coding, nothing that should interfere with.

thank you

Comment: The message you got when you tried to post this question without any code in it was quite clear. Please don't mark up nonsense as code to work around it. The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: thank you i wasn't able to do it so i tried to avoid it. with your guide links i did it so now should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem of your code is that js working before your html is rendered, which mean that any trying to get value from html will return `undefined`, `null`.

First of all you need to run your script in footer, or wrap it like this ( because your're using wordpress, so the `jquery` libraries will load by default )

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  //your code write here
});`

Comment: the probem now is that the slide option to change the pages results in a chrome error:

"[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive"

that is described here:

https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

Comment: Do you get that warning in the responsive mode of Chrome?